# word 2010 conditional blocks

Tags: ms-word, conditional-statements, mailmerge, word-2010

I'm creating a word document using mailmerge in word 2010 and I've got a table I need to show depending on whether a certain mergefield has a value or not. I've found a way to hide/show a line of text, but how can I do this with entire blocks (including tables, and possibly images and other mergefields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found it. It's actually exactly the same as with text, you can just insert everyhting in the IF field. I guess I was just messing up the syntax all the time.